# How to build tests using boost.test on mingw64?

Tags: boost, g++, mingw-w64, boost.test

I'm trying to write some code using the boost libraries on windows 10. To build the application I have chosen mingw64, which I have installed together with MSYS2.

After downloading and installing the boost libraries(1.76), I tried this example code (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost), which I built fine using this command:

```
g++ .\example.cpp -o test.exe -IC:\Users\Benelli\BoostLib\boost_1_76_0\boost_1_76_0
```

This example works on my system so I assumed that the boost libraries are installed correctly, although I did not build them, but I understood that the boost.test libary can be used as "header only".

I written a simple code following this tutorial:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

This code does not compile and I really do not get why. Is the boost.test library really "header_only"?
The command I used to build it was:

```
g++ .\boost_test_example.cpp -o boost_test.exe -IC:\Users\Benelli\BoostLib\boost_1_76_0\boost_1_76_0
```

Which gives this error message:
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

For the header only:

I think you need to use `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp` as per the boost docs at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/single_header_customizations/multiple_translation_units.html

I had a similar winMain error and had to the define for BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK to the top of the code (when i was linking against the libraries).

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

When not using the header only for the undefined references link with the boost test library, eg `-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt`.

Comment: Now is compiling, thanks a lot. Still, it seems that i'm encountering some issues given the output is: Test setup error: test tree is empty. Instead of  "*** No errors detected". Maybe you have experience with these behaviour too?